# Jow to enable the circular progress when the user clicks on submit in login page? [admin-on-rest]

Tags: admin-on-rest

How to enable the circular progress when user clicks on submit on the login page? I can able to see the loader symbol in the app bar on other pages but I'm not able to activate it on the login page.

Comment: Post the code, which you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

We need to add Custom reducer for login page. I did it in the following way.

1.1. Create a new login page. Just copy and paste the admin-on-rest login page code.
1.2. Update the propTypes like below

```
Login.propTypes = {
  ...propTypes,
  authClient: PropTypes.func,
  previousRoute: PropTypes.string,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  translate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  userLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isLogging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

1.3. Add the below line

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
      isLogging: state.loginReducer > 0
    };
}
```

1.4. Update the login page with below code.

```
const enhance = compose(
    translate,
    reduxForm({
        form: 'signIn',
        validate: (values, props) => {
            const errors = {};
            const { translate } = props;
            if (!values.username) errors.username = translate('aor.validation.required');
            if (!values.password) errors.password = translate('aor.validation.required');
            return errors;
        },
    }),
    connect(mapStateToProps, { userLogin: userLoginAction }),
);
export default enhance(Login);
```

1.5. Replace the submit button code

```
<CardActions>
    <RaisedButton type="submit" primary                                    disabled={isLogging} icon={isLogging && <CircularProgress size={25} thickness={2} />} label={translate('aor.auth.sign_in')}                                     fullWidth />
</CardActions>
```

1.6 The complete code for the login page is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { propTypes, reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import { Card, CardActions } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import CircularProgress from 'material-ui/CircularProgress';
import { cyan500, pinkA200, white } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';


import defaultTheme,  {translate, Notification, userLogin as userLoginAction } from 'admin-on-rest';


const styles = {
    main: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    card: {
        minWidth: 300,
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: '1em',
        textAlign: 'center ',

    },
      avatarText:{

        verticalAlign:'middle',
        fontSize:20,

      },
    form: {
        padding: '0 1em 1em 1em',
    },
    input: {
        display: 'flex',
    },
};

function getColorsFromTheme(theme) {
    if (!theme) return { primary1Color: cyan500, accent1Color: pinkA200 };
    const {
        palette: {
            primary1Color,
            accent1Color,
        },
      } = theme;
    return { primary1Color, accent1Color };
}

// see http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/material-ui/
const renderInput = ({ meta: { touched, error } = {}, input: { ...inputProps }, ...props }) =>
    <TextField
        errorText={touched && error}
        {...inputProps}
        {...props}
        fullWidth
    />;

class Login extends Component {

    login = (auth) => this.props.userLogin(auth, this.props.location.state ? this.props.location.state.nextPathname : '/');

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, submitting, theme, translate, isLogging } = this.props;
        const muiTheme = getMuiTheme(theme);
        const { primary1Color } = getColorsFromTheme(muiTheme);
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                <div style={{ ...styles.main, backgroundColor: primary1Color }}>
                    <Card style={styles.card}>
                        <div style={styles.avatar}>
                        <div>
                            <Avatar backgroundColor={white} src="EnsembleGreenLogo.png" size={45} /> 
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <span style={styles.avatarText}>Ensemble SmartWAN Manager</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.login)}>
                            <div style={styles.form}>
                                <div style={styles.input} >
                                    <Field
                                        name="username"
                                        component={renderInput}
                                        floatingLabelText={translate('aor.auth.username')}
                                        disabled={submitting}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div style={styles.input}>
                                    <Field
                                        name="password"
                                        component={renderInput}
                                        floatingLabelText={translate('aor.auth.password')}
                                        type="password"
                                        disabled={submitting}
                                    />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <CardActions>
                                <RaisedButton
                                    type="submit"
                                    primary
                                    disabled={isLogging}
                                    icon={isLogging && <CircularProgress size={25} thickness={2} />}
                                    label={translate('aor.auth.sign_in')}
                                    fullWidth
                                />
                            </CardActions>
                        </form>
                    </Card>
                    <Notification />
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

Login.propTypes = {
    ...propTypes,
    authClient: PropTypes.func,
    previousRoute: PropTypes.string,
    theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    translate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    userLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isLogging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

Login.defaultProps = {
    theme: defaultTheme,
};

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
      isLogging: state.loginReducer > 0
    };
}

const enhance = compose(
    translate,
    reduxForm({
        form: 'signIn',
        validate: (values, props) => {
            const errors = {};
            const { translate } = props;
            if (!values.username) errors.username = translate('aor.validation.required');
            if (!values.password) errors.password = translate('aor.validation.required');
            return errors;
        },
    }),
    connect(mapStateToProps, { userLogin: userLoginAction }),
);
export default enhance(Login);
```

2.1. Add a new file (src/loginReducer.js) in src folder with the below content

```
import { USER_LOGIN_LOADING, USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, USER_LOGIN_FAILURE, USER_CHECK } from 'admin-on-rest';

export default (previousState = 0, { type }) => {
    switch (type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_LOADING:
        return previousState + 1;
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    case USER_LOGIN_FAILURE:
    case USER_CHECK:
        return Math.max(previousState - 1, 0);
    default:
        return previousState;
    }
};
```

3.1 Update the app.js admin tag.

```
<Admin
      menu={createMenus}
      loginPage={Login}
      dashboard={Dashboard}
      appLayout={Layout}
      customReducers={{ loginReducer }} 
    >
```

3.2 import the login page and login reducers in app.js

```
import loginReducer from './loginReducer';
import Login from "./Login";
```